# How to add recurring task in MS Project server 2013?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, recurring-tasks

I have MS Project server 2013 and I have created one PWA and now I want to create a recurring task.

Can anyone tell me how can I create recurring task in a MS Project server 2013 web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic permission issue. You probably have been granted as "Team member only, therefore your actions are limited to:

```
Add a task to your task status
Assigning a task to another resource
Print a view
Create, view, and link project issues and risks
Approve or reject task updates
Get e-mail alerts or reminders when tasks change
```

If you are the one creating / removing tasks and milestones, you should be granted a Project Manager role